# How can I assure that a nested method inside another is called after calling the parent method in a unit test using Karma and Jasmine in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I've written this method in ordinary Angular component:

```
currentRoute(): void {
    const router: Router = this.injector.get(Router);
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            const currentUrl = val.url;
            this.displayLaneMakersLink =
                this.userService.userPermissions.hasLaneMakersLookupPermission;
            if (
                currentUrl.includes(this.searchResults) &&
                this.displayLaneMakersLink
            ) {
                this.laneMakerLinkVisible = true;
                this.getLaneMakersData();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I run that code, the properties `this.displayLaneMakersLink` and `currentUrl.includes(this.searchResults)` are both true, so the `this.getLaneMakersData();` method actually gets called. The first `if` is also `true`, but sadly, I'm having a hard time trying to demonstrate that this is actually true and that `displayLaneMakersLink` is being called.

The property `this.searchResult` looks exactly like this string = '/sl/(mobileOutlet:search-results)' and `this.displayLaneMakersLink` is `true`

I tried, failing completely, to create a unit test like this:

```
describe('currentRoute', () => {
    it('calls the getLaneMakersData method', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'getLaneMakersData');
        component.currentRoute();
        expect(component.getLaneMakersData).toHaveBeenCalled;
    });
});
```

It fails with this error: 'Error: Expected false to equal true.'

I'm calling the parent method in the `.spec` file using `component.currentRoute()`, however, the assertion of the inner method `component.getLaneMakersData` getting called fails. Why is this happening? How could I make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `expect(xyz).toEqual(true)` but I think you're misusing `toHaveBeenCalled`.

Change this line:

```
expect(component.getLaneMakersData).toHaveBeenCalled;
```

To:

```
// add brackets at the end
expect(component.getLaneMakersData).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I think you also may need help with mocking the router and the events as well so it goes inside of the subscribe block.